# using sapply with two or more variables

Tags: r, apply

I would like to evaluate two different variables using `is.null`:

```
a<-c(1,2)
b<-NULL
sapply(c(a,b),is.null)
```

However, I got a warning that stating that the condition has `length > 1` and only the first element will be used. The output I got showed this as it only evaluted `FALSE, FALSE` rather than `FALSE, FALSE, TRUE`.

How can I successfully run the `is.null` function on multiple variables?

Comment: `c(a, b)`, removes the NULL.  But `NULL` can exist as a `list` element. `c(a, list(b))`,with this you can get `sapply(c(a, list(b)), is.null)#
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, the issue is that `NULL` cannot exist in a vector.  When we do `c`, we are concatenating one vector with another and whatever `NULL` elements are present in one vector gets lost.  Instead, place it in a `list`

```
sapply(c(a, list(b)), is.null)
```